# How to Bypass High Water-Mark in Marketing Cloud Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I need to design my Journey in a way that the same person can re-enter it multiple times. The Contact Entry settings of my Journey is already set to "Re-entry anytime" but I still can't make it work. I did some research and apparently it has something to do with "High Water-Mark". What do I need to do to meet my specifications?

Comment: Have you configured your evaluation settings correctly? This is what controls your "High Level Water Mark". I can't tell you how to configure it without knowing your entry source and how your query type is setup to collate your journey data.

Comment: @thechrishaddad I'm using Salesforce Data as my Entry Source with Lead: Lead ID as the selected object. Records enters the Journey on "is Created" and "is Updated", with a few specific Event Criteria and has no Filter Criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce Data Entry Source is not related to a high water mark, as this is purely for Data Extension Entry Source. Hence any trigger from Sales Cloud will push a contact into the journey - regardless of high watermark in the underlying data extension.

What you need to keep in mind for Salesforce Data Entry Source is, that it only evaluates the record once criteria switches from "not met" to "met". Hence if you are looking at "is Updated" logic, and let's say monitor *isMarketingRelevant* field, being boolean and default false, you will succeed by changing the field from false to true. However, keeping it *true* and saving the record will NOT trigger the journey. You  must change it to *false*, save, and then change back to *true*.