# Hight water mark event

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is Hight water mark related only Event entry source?

Does not occur when you set as an entry source data extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303077/how-to-bypass-high-water-mark-in-marketing-cloud-journey-builder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Bypass High Water-Mark in Marketing Cloud Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303077/how-to-bypass-high-water-mark-in-marketing-cloud-journey-builder)

Comment: -.- You just linked to the same post 4 hours later :D